# Problems joining to Active Directory

Tags: dns, domain, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am having difficulty connecting my laptop to my domain. I have recently set up a domain controller in my flat but, when I try and connect to it using my machine, it says "An attempt to resolve the DNS name failed" and when I try and type in the full domain name instead of the NetBIOS name, it tells me that no domain controller can be found. I manually set the DNS server to point to my domain controller but it still doesn't work.

I did think that renaming the domain (using this guide: http://www.rebeladmin.com/2015/05/step-by-step-guide-to-rename-active-directory-domain-name/) might help but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Can you guys help me because I do not know what the hell is wrong. I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard on my server and the Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation on my laptop. Should I put the DNS of the server to its own IP address?

Comment: Did you actually enable the DNS server on the server itself?

Comment: Is TPM enabled in the BIOS of the laptop? I've had issues with some laptops not being able to join a domain with this turned on.

Comment: I did enable the DNS server of the server, I don't know about TPM so will check but the time was set wrong in the BIOS of the server and not sure if I set it to the correct time before installing AD

Comment: What do you get if you run NSLookup <domain server's FQDN>?  Can you ping the server by IP? How about by name?

Comment: I was able to ping it by name and IP address yet, when I did NSLookup I got non existent domain

Comment: When I do ipconfig /all on the server, the DNS server is 127.0.0.1, I assume it doesn't have to be 192.168.0.1 which is the IP address of my server

Comment: on your laptop, are you using 192.168.0.1 as one of your DNS server?

Comment: Yes, it is my preferred DNS server

Comment: what is the FQDN (fully qualified domain name) that you are using for the DNS/AD server?   You can tell by going to Windows Explorer > Right Click on Computer > Properties > under Computer name and domain settings click Change Settings, it should show up under the Computer Name tab where it says Full Computer Name: server.whatever.local

Comment: Reset Windows Firewall on the laptop. Disable/remove any other firewall software...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access your SYSVOL, there's definitely something wrong with you DC or DNS.
- Make sure the proper services in the domain controller is on, and run analyzer to ensure your DC is healthy
- Make sure your DNS is properly advertised
[Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759260.aspx)
[Active Directory Best Practices Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378893.aspx)
- Test telnet port 389 and 3269 from this new machine to the DC

Comment: I can now view SYSVOL but I am noticing events in the event log. In the AD event log I get: The local domain controller could not connect with the following domain controller hosting the following directory partition to resolve distinguished names. 
 
Domain controller:
 
Directory partition:
mediatwist.local 
 
Additional Data 
Error value:
1355 The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. 
Internal ID:
3200e24

Comment: I assume your DNS only has one record, and it's pointing to your internal DNS (in mediatwist.local)? Where are you getting the Ad events from? The DC? What does your AD BPA returned as a result? Were those resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your home router is using 192.168.0.1 as it's IP address? Try changing the server to a different address.

edit: OK, sorry, I can't comment yet so I had to make this an answer.

Comment: The server and the router are not using the same IP address, I am unable to access SYSVOL when I go to the server so I figure the problem may be connected with that

Comment: I have sorted the issue now